# TypeError: expected string or buffer regex python

Tags: python, regex, list, find

I have a list that i take from a document. It looks like this:

> [ u'Informuar:PK,SHME SHZSH,Sh\xebrbimet tjera', u'Informuar:PK,SHME
>   SHZSH,Sh\xebrbimet tjera', u'00:30 K\xebrkohet ndihm\xeb mjek\xebsor
>   p\xebr nj\xeb person t\xeb s\xebmur 84-vjeqar p\xebrball Post\xebs
>   n\xeb Komoran.', u'Informuar:PK,SHME SHZSH,Sh\xebrbimet
>   tjera',Sh\xebrbimet tjera', `u'07Policia e Kosov\xebs    '`, '06',
>   u'Sherbime dhe te tjers', '16', u'1 Sh\xebrbimi Medical
>   ', '1', u'Sherb. Zjarrfik\xebs      22', u'17T\xeb tjera
>   ', '17', '  ', u'Gjat\xeb 24 or\xebve t\xeb fundit kemi pranuar  24
>   raste si dhe  376 thirrje prej k\xebtyre rasteve  nuk 
>   kemi  pasur  intervenime nga SHZSH-ja.']

I have many lists like this. There is an element  `u'07Policia e Kosov\xebs    '` that is in all lists but that number 07 it's unique for each list., so it can be any number...
I defined a regular expression for this, so I can check in list and find that element so later I can take its index.

```
find_element = re.match(r'((\u\'\w\w\Policia\s\e\s\Kosov*))', results, flags=0)
if find_element:
    print find_element
```

When I execute this I get this error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: `re.match()` takes a string as the 2nd argument.  It looks like you're passing a list.

Comment: @Jkdc thank you for your answer! What should i use for list?

Comment: Just make it `re.match(r'((\u\'\w\w\Policia\s\e\s\Kosov*))', ''.join(results), flags=0)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193521/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer

Comment: You probably also want to use `re.search()`.  That regex you have won't work with `match()` and the string in your example.

Comment: @Unni that convert it on a string so I have this: .. Sherbimet tjeraPolicia e Kosovves.. so then I can't take the index of that string?