# Why am I getting decoder errors when turning my JSON array into a Python list using json.loads?

Tags: python, json, decoder

Below is the error code I received on my Terminal call of "python lastYearArray.py". (I'm on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9.5, editing my Python program in jEdit). According to this link: [TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193521/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer) it appears that the function I am using doesn't take lists either. I would just be working with the JSON file instead of converting it, but this particular JSON data has no headers or element tags, such as "fruits: apple, banana, orange"; it only has a long string of numbers separated by commas and braces.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "lastYearAnalysis.py", line 8, in <module>
        PyListData = json.loads(lastYearArray)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

However,I don't know why it is telling me about a decoder, because as you can see from my rather minimal code here:

```
#Write json array to a python list to find the iterative location of max value
#should return a value such as "[n]" on req for max

import requests
import json

lastYearArray = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/stats/contributors')
PyListData = json.loads(lastYearArray)
print data[PyListData]

#TODO: ask for max value
```

I'm not using an explicit decoder function that I can see; I'm using json.loads. I should add that I am certainly a Python novice with regards to lists and JSON array decoding. Any info, however basic, that you can provide would be immensely helpful to me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can simply [edit] your question and add the missing information to it.

Answer (score 1):

[`requests.get`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.get) returns a [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object. That object is not a string object, so you cannot pass it to `json.loads`.

You have to get the response object’s using [`response.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text), and pass that to `json.loads`:

```
lastYearArrayResponse = requests.get('…')
data = json.loads(lastYearArrayResponse.text)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [`response.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.json) method to get the parsed response since requests already comes with built-in support for JSON responses:

```
lastYearArrayResponse = requests.get('…')
data = lastYearArrayResponse.json()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! So, you're saying that json.loads actually creates a local file and puts all the data there? If that's true then a) where does it put the file? and b) how can I search the file for a maximum? I am only familiar with Java arrays, so I don't really know how python arrays work in terms of sequencing, especially because they're called "lists." I need to be able to search that file for the maximum value and return the place of the highest value within the list so that I can calculate what day that commit was on. Can I do a max search with the code I have now?

Comment: What? Where did you take the “creates a local file” part from? No, absolutely not. You are trying to parse some JSON response from a webservice; the webservice returns a string. You parse that string as an in-memory object using `json.loads()` (or `response.json()`). That returns then an object that represents that content. If the response was a list of things, then that deserialized object is a list. Once deserialized, you can handle that like every other list.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `.text` at the end of line **lastYearArray =** to get the HTML source of the webpage.

Also, I think the last line is not correct...

Comment: Thanks for the response!